# What is the meaning of the word "rain-maker"? How did this originate?

Tags: meaning, etymology

What is the meaning of the word "rain-maker"? How did this originate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Rain-maker** or **rainmaker** originates from [native American tribal magicians](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=rainmaker) (etymonline) and has come into English language around 1775.

It is used of a professional that is great in his field (seemingly magical) or somebody  believed to be able to produce rain. Especially somebody generating a great deal.

See [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rainmaker)

Comment: I've always understood it to mean someone who brings business to a firm, as a literal rainmaker might bring rain to a farmer's crops. (As in the definition following your link and looking at the "Thesaurus" part of the page.)